# What does "let me at her" mean? What does "at" mean?

Tags: prepositions, idioms, expressions

This is from *Good Luck Charlie*.

Dad and mom are dating. They are having a dinner at a restaurant. Charlie's siblings take her to the restaurant. Teddy goes up to mom, saying,

> We think you must be missing Charlie, so we brought her.

Mom said, bla bla bla...,

> **Let me at her**.

She's trying to stand up.

Teddy says,

> Mom, mom, sit down. Let me bring her to you.

In this context, what does "let me at her" mean? What does "at" mean? What is the verb that comes before it and which is omitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Let me at X" is a common expression that normally means, "Let me attack X". Like, if you got in a fight, and your friends grabbed you to pull you out, you might yell, "Let me at him!", meaning you wanted to continue fighting.

In a context like this scene from Good Luck Charlie, it can jokingly be used to mean, *Let me "attack" X with love, or kisses, or something else nice*.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could it be "let me get at her", with "get at" meaning to "reach"?

Comment: @Stephen No, that's a different verb